# Yii2: Cannot process to get Session

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using Yii2 Advanced version.

This is Login Model:

```
namespace common\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

class LoginForm extends Model{  
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    public $verifyCode;

    const BACKEND_TEST = 'none';
    const BACKEND_ID = 'test';
    const BACKEND_USERNAME = 'backend_username';

    private $user;

    public function rules(){
        return [            [['username','password'],'required','message'=>'{attribute}required...'],
['username','validateUser'],          ['verifyCode','captcha','captchaAction'=>'login/captcha','message'=>'Wrong'],
            ];
    }

    public function validateUser($attribute,$params){
        $user = User::findOne(['username'=>$this->username]);
        if(!$user || (md5($this->password) != $user['password'])){
            $this->addError('password','Wrong>_<...');
        }else{
        $this->user = $user;
        }
    }

    public function login(){
        if(!$this->user){
            return false;
        }
        var_dump($this->userInfo());
        $this->createSession();
        return true;

    }

    private function createSession(){
        //Yii::$app->session->open();
        Yii::$app->set(self::BACKEND_ID,$this->user['id']);
        Yii::$app->set(self::BACKEND_USERNAME,$this->user['username']);

    }
public function userInfo(){
    return $this->user;
}
```

Also, there is LoginController that I think have no issue, and next thing is when user try to login and session will be opened, and direct to site page.
Here is the sitecontroller:

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        //var_dump(Yii::$app->session->get(common\models\LoginForm::BACKEND_ID));
        var_dump(LoginForm::userInfo());
        return $this->renderPartial('index');
    }
```

Every time I try to login and the Error message comes out and provides:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> Unexpected configuration type for the "test" component: integer

How to solve the issue, and I try to get $user that stores all the data and it seems to fail?

main.php:

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => ['smister' => [
            'class' => 'backend\modules\smister\smister',
        ],],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: Show  your main.php in backend/config

Comment: @scaisEdge Hi,the main codes have added.

Comment: I have posted an answer .. hope is waht you are  looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
 Yii::$app->set(self::BACKEND_ID,$this->user['id']);
```

probably for set a param value .. 
but the Class yii\web\Application  (alias   Yii::$app->set ) contain a function named set() that register component  ..(so your error : Unexpected configuration type for the "test" component: integer)  in this way your code is misundestood  by Yii2  because your costant  BACKEND_ID = 'test';  is not a component id but the key for   a param

see this reference for check

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-di-servicelocator.html#set()-detail

for you scope if you need param you can use  the file param.php

returning the param you need

file config/param.php

```
<?php
   return [
     'test' => 'my_initial_value',
];
```

and you can access this param simply  using

```
 \Yii::$app->params['test'],
```

or you can simply setting runtime

```
  \Yii::$app->params['test'] = 'Your_value';
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but cannot solve the problem, I was following a tutorial, probably I need to contact that teacher directly. Anyway, selected as best rely.